# Cannot enable cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 on GCE Debian Jessie instance

Tags: linux, docker, debian, google-compute-engine

In order to support Docker memory limits / quotas I'd like to enable the

```
cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
```

Linux kernel command line options on my Debian Jessie Google Cloud Compute Engine instances. After adding them to `/etc/default/grub`, updating and rebooting I can see the options being active in `/proc/cmdline`:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=aeb374a4-1a04-4ed7-adac-d5c57b350575 ro console=ttyS0,38400n8 elevator=noop cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
```

However, `docker info` still complains about them being disabled:

```
$ docker info
[...]
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
[...]
```

Any ideas? Has the kernel included with the GCE Debian image built without support for these features?

Comment: See also: [Limit memory usage for a single Linux process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/4784)

Answer (score 7):

Update `/etc/default/grub` and set:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

run `update-grub && reboot`

Instead of `docker info` (which seems to be buggy) use rather `lxc-checkconfig` or [check-config.sh](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh) from Docker (moby) repository:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/check-config.sh && bash check-config.sh
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `cgroup_enable=memory` parameter? It is not documented here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: @adgud Enables hard memory limits for `cgroup` tasks. Otherwise memory limits are not enforced by kernel.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I've made some tests and this does not seem mandatory to me.